# Chocolate dynamics

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry

Now I have found a possible model on how to describe chocolate when it is chewed. It has to do with geometrical transformations when a curve $\gamma$ intersects a manifold $M$.

The chocolate is simply the manifold $M$ at the beginning. When the teeth that propagating along the curve $\gamma$ cross through the chocolate, one has the geometrical Transformation $Hom(M,M_\gamma)$ with the 2-connected-component-manifold $M_\gamma$. For the cuts along the curves $\Gamma, \Sigma, ...$ acting on the manifold $M$ I write for the resulting manifold: $M_{\Gamma, \Sigma, ...}$. If $[\partial M]$ is a curve lying entirely on the manifold boundary $\partial M$ one has an isomorphism $Hom(M,M_{[\partial M]})$ because a cut along the Surface doesn't Change the manifold.

Now I can introduce a vector field $t_\mu(x)$ on the manifold that describes a Tangent vector of any cutting curve (if and only if a cutting curve is located at the Point $x \in M$); otherwise (if there is no cutting curve) this vector is Zero. I obtain a discontinuous vector field, but despide discontinuity I try to define an equation:

$\partial_\nu t_\mu + \alpha_{\nu \mu}^\lambda t_\lambda = 0$.

The quantity $\alpha_{\nu \mu}^\lambda $ is a hyperreal number (a number which can be also infinity or infinitesimal). Solving this equation by the vector field would give a parallel Propagator from which several tensorial quantities can be derived (e.g. the curvature). In some cases, appropiate choice of the parallel Transport result in non-infinite curvatures.

Are my thoughts plausible for describing the geometry of the chocolate when it is chewed? Which branch of geometry deals with the above Situation? Every reply will by highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this more appropriate for math.SE?  (Seems like a pure diff. geom. problem)

Comment: a) chocolate melts in the mouth in addition to chewing, so your components might become connected again, b) whatever you want with hyperreal numbers should be possible also within standard calculus, c) what do you actually want to describe? What level of accuracy do you want to have?

Comment: a) and b) This model respects also the molten chocolate geometry, because the vector field then will be defined everywhere on the manifold without discontinuities since the melting is modeled by adding intersections with infinitely many curves (maybe the curves are generated randomly by a stochastic process model). c) I want to know whether the curvature Tensor is nonvanishing on the chocolate, because nonvanishing curvature implies incompatibility for the Deformation Gradient.

Comment: do you want to give a shot at the ig nobel? ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is mostly about mathematics of folding transformations rather than physics.